# Shiny - DT - Single row selection, across several DT::tables

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

In the example below, I have 3 `DT::datatables`. I want the user to be able to select no more than one row from all these tables. I thence use `dataTableProxy` and `selectRow`, as per the section "Manipulate An Existing DataTables Instance" in the [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html). It works fine.

However, in my application, I have 24 (call that value `N`) tables. If I try to adapt the code below to my 24 tables page, I get an horrendous number of lines of code.

What is a smarter way of doing this?

In particular, how can I:

- declare the observers dynamically? (answered by user5029763)
- know which table (not row) has been    clicked upon last? (ie. how to re write `reactiveText()`?)

**EDIT :** I copied in user5029763's answer (see below) in the code below.

```
DTWrapper <- function(data, pl = 5, preselec = c()){
  datatable(data,
            options = list(pageLength = pl, dom='t',ordering=F),
            selection = list(mode = 'single', selected= preselec),
            rownames = FALSE)
}
resetRows <- function(proxies, self){
  for (i in 1:length(proxies)){
    if (self != i){
      proxies[[i]] %>% selectRows(NULL)
    }
  }
}

lapply(1:3, function(id) {
  observe({
    rownum <- input[[paste0("tab",id,"_rows_selected")]]
    if (length(rownum) > 0) { resetRows(proxyList(), id) }
  })
})

server = function(input, output) {

  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(head(mtcars[,1:3]), input$selectTop))
  output$tab2 <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(head(mtcars[,1:3]), input$selectTop))
  output$tab3 <- DT::renderDataTable(DTWrapper(head(mtcars[,1:3]), input$selectTop))

  proxyList <- reactive({
    proxies = list()
    for (i in 1:3){
      tableID <- paste("tab", i, sep="")
      proxies[[i]] = dataTableProxy(tableID)
    }
    return(proxies)
  }) 

  reactiveText <- reactive({
    rownum1 <- input$tab1_rows_selected
    rownum2 <- input$tab2_rows_selected
    rownum3 <- input$tab3_rows_selected
    if (length(rownum1) > 0){return(c(rownum1, 1))}
    if (length(rownum2) > 0){return(c(rownum2, 2))}
    if (length(rownum3) > 0){return(c(rownum3, 3))}
  })

  output$txt1 <- renderText({
    paste("You selected row ", reactiveText()[1]
          , " from table ", reactiveText()[2], ".", sep="")
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(4,DT::dataTableOutput("tab1"))
             , column(4,DT::dataTableOutput("tab2"))
             , column(4, DT::dataTableOutput("tab3")))
    ,fluidRow(column(4,textOutput("txt1")))
  ),
  server = server
)
```

The `textOutput` is: "You selected the Xth row from the Yth table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## After edit:

You could try [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Another way would be a `lapply`.

```
lapply(1:3, function(id) {
    observe({
      rownum <- input[[paste0("tab",id,"_rows_selected")]]
      if (length(rownum) > 0) {
        resetRows(proxyList(), id)
        
        msg <- paste0("You selected row ", rownum, ", from table ", id, ".")
        output$txt1 <- renderText(msg)
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thx for this answer. That takes care of the cleanup of previous selections, which is great. But going this way, how can other function from your code retrieve the `rownum` (to update an `Xoutput`for instance) ? I am not sure I am clear, but I have try to update my Q to make this concern more explit. Thx-